# Zlib Kernel Module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, zlib, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to implement a kernel module which uses zlib, so is there any Zlib module available for linux-2.6.17.8?.

If I need to convert the source files of zlib to kernel space I need to replace malloc, function calls, assertions etc?

Answer (score 5):

It is already in the Linux kernel. See `include/linux/zlib.h`; this has been in the Git tree since its initial conversion (at Linux 2.6.12).

You can `git grep` to find examples of usages, such as in `ppp_deflate.c`.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the reply. I need to use zlib version 1.2.1 and the linux 2.6.17.8 version supports zlib 1.1.3 version. what is the best approach to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

The kernel already as support for zlib compression (at least for decompressing itself).

Look into ./include/linux/zlib.h and lib/zlib_*